# Chrome disconnects after WebSockets handshake

Tags: c#, google-chrome, websocket

I am trying to get a simple WebSocket example to work on my machine (`localhost`), I got JavaScript and C# running just fine and connecting, except that Chrome disconnects after handshake.

I have searched all morning and I think it has something to do with the same domain policy, as another "question" suggests, I have updated my browser to the latest version (`12.xxx`).

However I couldnt find a solution to my problem.

I am using on the C# side:

```
ConnectionOrigin = "http://localhost:8080";
ServerLocation = "ws://localhost:8181/test";
```

And I am running the JavaScript using a normal HTML file open straight from disk (`file:///` on the url bar). I have also tried using XAMPP to host it locally but I always have the same problem.

Attached goes the log output of the C# program:

```
   New connection from 127.0.0.1:8181 requested. Handshaking ...
Reading handshake ...
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:8181
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: R 506   I   2D }6 qFB  G0`@88J? 4
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: y  20   8403!24  L 5 8

Sending handshake ...
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:8080
WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8181/test


New connection from 127.0.0.1:8181 established.
http://localhost:8080
Data sent to the client ["Time at the server: 23-07-2011 12:57:27"]
Client disconnected.
Waiting for another connection attempt ...
```

Comment: What WebSocket server are you using? What error do you get from Chrome (in the Chrome javascript console)? Also, the handshake value you show are for the Hixie-76 version of the protocol but they are incomplete as shown. The client should send 8 random bytes at the end of the handshake. The server should be sending back 16 bytes that are based on key1, key2 and the 8 random bytes from the client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of this request:

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: localhost:8181
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: R 506   I   2D }6 qFB  G0`@88J? 4
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: y  20   8403!24  L 5 8
```

the response must be:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8181/test

the response code here
```

So:

- It's `WebSocket` and not `Web Socket` in the first line.
- It's `Sec-WebSocket-...` and not `WebSocket-...`.
- You did not include the response code which is the essential part of the handshake (of which the construction is described in [the specs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76#section-5.2)).
- Also, you should use `\r\n` and not `\n` (in case you didn't already).

On a side note, you might want to consult `chrome://net-internals/` (the `Events` tab and then look for the appropriate `SOCKET_STREAM`) to see what response Chrome actually received.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to set `Connection: keep-alive`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: Replacing : 
Handshake += "Connection: Upgrade" + Environment.NewLine;
With:
Handshake += "Connection: Keep-Alive" + Environment.NewLine;

Gave me no results.